# Normalize Small Probabilities in Python

Tags: python, probability

I have a list of probabilities, which I need to normalize to equal 1.0.
e.g. `probs = [0.01,0.03,0.005]`

I realize that this is done by dividing each probability by the sum of `probs`. However, if the probabilities become really small, Python will tell me that `sum(probs)=0.0`. I understand that this is an underflow issue. I suppose I should use the log of each probability. How would I do this?

Comment: do you want them to be between [1-0] ?This is what normalizing mean.

Comment: I think he wants to multiply each value by some constant such that `sum(probs)` equals one.

Comment: Are you sure that's not a printing issue? If the individual elements in the array are not exactly zero, the sum should be machine-representable, but maybe your printing options are only showing it as zero.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sum of even very small floating point values will never truly be 0; they may be *close* to zero, but can never be exactly zero.

Just divide 1 by their sum, and multiply the probabilities by that factor:

```
def normalize(probs):
    prob_factor = 1 / sum(probs)
    return [prob_factor * p for p in probs]
```

Some probabilities may make up but a *very small* percentage in the total sum, of course, and that percentage may approach zero. But this just means that when normalising you may end up with normalized probabilities that are either very close to zero, or if smaller than the smallest representable floating point value, equal to zero. The latter only happens if there are probabilities in the list that are so much smaller than the others that they no longer represent anything close to something that'll ever occur.

Demo:

```
>>> def normalize(probs):
...     prob_factor = 1 / sum(probs)
...     return [prob_factor * p for p in probs]
... 
>>> normalize([0.0000000001,0.000000000003,0.000000000000005])
[0.9708266589000533, 0.029124799767001597, 4.854133294500266e-05]
```

And the extreme case:

```
>>> import sys
>>> normalize([sys.float_info.max, sys.float_info.min])
[0.9999999999999999, 0.0]
>>> normalize([sys.float_info.max, sys.float_info.min])[-1] == 0
True
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure why this still isn't working for me -- it makes sense.  I suspect the zeroes lie deeper in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a scale factor to avoid the underflow problem, either manually entered or automatically calculated, e.g.:

```
import math
no_z = ([x for x in probs if x > 0.0])
if len(no_z) == 0:
   print "Unable to calculate with 0.0 as all the probabilities"
order = int(-math.log10(min(no_z)))
if order > 0:
   order = 0
sf = 10**order
scaled = [x * sf for x in probs]
tot = sum(scaled)
norm = [x/tot for x in scaled]
```

Of course you would probably be better off just using [bigfloat](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bigfloat/) or numpy and doing high precision maths.